# Snort rule update issue

Tags: snort

after updating rules with pulledport (/usr/local/bin/pulledpork.pl -c /usr/local/etc/snort/pulledpork.conf -T –l) snort (barnyard for sure) stop working, and freez at "+[ Signature Suppress list ]+".
If i start snort with "-A console" parameter it's show working test rule
I tried to comment "snort.rules', but it's don't help.
Debian 7.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it's work fine, after update rules Snort satrting 3-5 min, so all and i need is just wait =)